# Issue adding IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am using `Asp Net core 3` and trying to add identity core. When I add `IdentityDbContext` it gives error and if I change `IdentityDbContext` to `DbContext` error is gone. The same issue is when I try to add `SQL sever` using `IdentityDbContext` but no error when using `DbContext`.
I am getting the following error ***"There is no implicit reference conversion from `IdentityDbContext` to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`"***
.[image: Click to view error] 
I added the following NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore** and **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver**. Kindly help.

Comment: Which error is there?

Comment: "There is no implicit reference conversion from IdentityDbContext to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext".

Comment: Put your cusror on `IdentityDbContext` and press F12, look carefully at where it takes you.

Comment: I navigated to IdentityDbContext class, its empty nothing in that class. Why is that so ? While when i navigate to DbContext there are all lot of methods there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Put your cursor on IdentityDbContext and press F12, ...
>
> > I navigated to IdentityDbContext class, its empty nothing in that class.

That means that you have accidentally created that class through Intellisense. Look at where it is located: in your project, not the library.

Find that class in your project and remove it. Then fix whatever references/usings the Startup class needs.